# why is my hugo site not building on github pages?

Tags: github-pages, hugo

So my hugo site is working on localhost and doesn't work on github pages.

My repo is at:
https://github.com/ba789/ba789.github.io

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"? Where are you hosting it? I don't see a `gh_pages` branch in the repository to which you've linked.

Comment: On github it states that the source is being built from my master branch

Comment: Your repository contains the *source* for your website, but would need to arrange for Github to run `hugo` to render your pages. By itself, GitHub can only serve up static HTML or a site designed for use with [Jekyll](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll). If you're using Hugo, it's your job to produce the static HTML output necessary for your site.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the Hugo documentation "[Host on GitHub](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/)", but you would need two different repositories:

> As mentioned in the [GitHub Pages documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#user--organization-pages), you can host a user/organization page in addition to project pages.
> Here are the key differences in GitHub Pages websites for Users and Organizations:
>
> - You must use a `<USERNAME>.github.io` to host your generated content
> - **Content from the main branch will be used to publish your GitHub Pages site**
>
> This is a much simpler setup as **your Hugo files and generated content are published into two different repositories**.